# Using IPhoneService in Caliburn Micro PCL

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, portable-class-library

I'm currently trying Caliburn Micro in PCL where my viewmodels are located. This PCL project is currently used by a Windows Phone application project, where I would like to use IPhoneService to manage with tombstoning in Windows Phone. The problem is, as the PCL version is not platform specific, it does not contains the IPhoneService.
Same for INavigation service, I'm quite surprise that it is not included in the PCL version of Caliburn ? How is it supposed to be used?

My question is : How can I manage tombstoning in PCL ? What's the way to do it ?

**Comment:**

I think I got it : I will have my generics ViewModels (platform independent code) in PCL project. Then, from my Windows Phone project, I will inherit those ViewModels and add them specific platform dependent code. This way, everything is kept separated and should be good!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it : I will have my generics ViewModels (platform independent code) in PCL project. Then, from my Windows Phone project, I will inherit those ViewModels and add them specific platform dependent code. This way, everything is kept separated and should be good!